# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access."

Tags: javascript, angularjs

By using Angular I am building mobile app and also I was able to access all RESTAPI in my local system, http://localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy . Suddenly I am geting this issues, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access i.e XMLHttpRequest cannot load.

Comment: Add some code, please?

Comment: What is the URL of the REST API endpoint you're trying to hit? This is a cross-origin problem. Due to the browser's same-origin policy you'll need to use CORS on your server for cross-origin requests.

Comment: put that error in search box....will find lots of results

Comment: In fact ...look at the numerous matches in ***Related Links*** on right side of this page

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)